# how to migrate data from blob datatype from oracle to SQL using java where in file stream I am sending only table dynamically

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

```
I tried to migrate the blob data from oracle to MySQL workbench 8.0.17 
but each time i am getting different error.
```

In FileInputStream i am passing only table name (table Name variable 
   here). I have to get the data from the table (oracle database not from 
   any file) itself for blob and Migrate it to MYSQL rest datatype is 
   working fine for me.

But blob datatype is not getting migrate.

Attached query i tried.

Help for this really needed as i am stuck here and over all platform i 
   tried no luck in that.

```
 String insertSql = "INSERT INTO "+ tableName +"enter code here values(" 
 + insertValues + ")"; 
 System.out.println("insertSql"+insertSql);
  PreparedStatement storeStatement = donn.prepareStatement(insertSql);
  ResultSet loadedData = stmt.executeQuery();
        if (loadedData != null) {
            ResultSetMetaData columns1 = loadedData.getMetaData();
            int i = 1;
            int j=1;
            while ( i <= columns1.getColumnCount()) {
                //System.out.println(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(i));
                type = columns1.getColumnTypeName(i);
                String K= columns.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println("k==============="+K);
                System.out.println(type);
                if (type == "BLOB") {`enter code here`
                 System.out.println("ddddd");
                String h= columns.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println("h==============="+h);
                //System.out.println("input in sql "+input);
                int ch;
                while((ch = input.read()) != -1)
                { image = (Blob) loadedData.getBlob("bild");
                     InputStream binaryStream enter code here= 
                 image.getBinaryStream(1, image.length());
                 //while (loadedData.next()) {
               String l= columns.getColumnName(i);
                System.out.println("l==============="+l);
                  InputStream m = loadedData.getBinaryStream(l);
                     System.out.println("input1input1input1--------- 
                         "+m);
                  byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                      while (input.read(buffer) > 0) {
                          System.out.println(buffer);
                           input.close();
                         }
                 }// stmt.setBlob(j, input);
              storeStatement.setBinaryStream(1,input,input.available());
                  storeStatement.setString(1, 
          loadedData.getString(columnNames.get(i)));
        } else {
                 System.out.println("fffff");
        }
             i++;
    } 
       }
    }
 }

Actual result is that blob should be Migrated from oracle to mysql 
smoothly.
```

Comment: Sorry, your question is not stated clearly. Your code is far too long, you should provide a "minimal example" of what is your problem. I don't even understand what you mean with "migrate a blob" : are you (1) migrating your program from oracle to mysql ? Or (2) your program should connect to two databases and copy data from oracle to mysql?

Comment: your 2nd question is correct that my program should connect to two databases and copy data from oracle to mysql.

Comment: but conection part is done as well as the data of datatype varchar2,Nvarchar, date, are getting transferred but me facing issue in transferring data of Blob,clob datatype from oracle to MYSQL

Comment: I think you cannot use a INSERT statement with blobs. You have to deal with blobs in a different way. Do these examples help you? https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.sql.Blob&method=setBinaryStream

Comment: hi ...I tried all these examples but not got any result ....This i require to do it in the production Environment so wants to work a way round other wise have to go for csv option for the table migration which will again be huge as number of tables will increase  or hard code transfer which is not the option.